# How do you pass environment variables from the Source to the Build in AWS CodePipelines?

Tags: amazon-web-services, webhooks, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, github-webhook

In AWS CodeBuild, it's incredibly easy to pass environment variables, as shown in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html). If I want to get the event trigger reference, I can use the variable `CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER`, which is context-sensitive: for a GitHub `PUSH` event, this will be the branch name, but for a `PULL_REQUEST_CREATED` or `PULL_REQUEST_UPDATED` event, this will be the PR number.

So the problem is this: when using AWS CodePipeline, the CodeBuild project "source" is the CodePipeline instead of the GitHub webhook. Suddenly, `CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER` is an empty string and doesn't seem to know about anything about the original GitHub webhook event that triggered the CodePipeline.

How does one access those environment variables using a CodeBuild project that is triggered by a CodePipeline? It seems to be a use case that AWS overlooked, so it might be a bug. Unfortunately, very difficult to submit a bug report with only a basic access account.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. In this particular case, CodePipeline is the one making start-build API call to start the build. CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER is CodeBuild specific and will only be set when the webhook invokes CodeBuild.

If you want to know the webhook that triggered pipeline, you can use list-webhooks [1] API call with additional filters based on pipeline name to get the webhook details.

Ref:
[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codepipeline/list-webhooks.html

## Edit 1:

I was wrong that list-webhooks will get you the required information. I did some tests and it only gives you the list of webhooks defined for the Source action.

The closest I can get is using "list-pipeline-executions" [2] CLI call in your CodeBuild buildspec.

If you run this command:

```
$ aws codepipeline list-pipeline-executions --pipeline-name <Pipeline_Name> --region us-east-1 --max-items 1
```

It will give you output similar to this:

```
{
    "pipelineExecutionSummaries": [
        {
            "pipelineExecutionId": "ccdd87a0-41e4-4489-9332-0720dc526b37",
            "status": "InProgress",
            "startTime": 1573037463.245,
            "lastUpdateTime": 1573037463.245,
            "sourceRevisions": [
                {
                    "actionName": "Source",
                    "revisionId": "4d3bcb17e4a71e3d4bf15215954172639716c326",
                    "revisionSummary": "Merge pull request #3 from shariqmus/readme-edits\n\nUpdate Code.py",
                    "revisionUrl": "https://github.com/shariqmus/hello-world/commit/4d3bcb17e4a71e3d4bf15215954172639716c326"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "NextToken": "eyJuZXh0VG9rZW4iOiBudWxsLCAiYm90b190cnVuY2F0ZV9hbW91bnQiOiAxfQ=="
}
```

The 'revisionSummary' has the PR details. You can filter this value using 'jq' [3], so the command in your build spec will look something like:

1. Make sure your CodeBuild project's service role has permission to do 'ListPipelineExecutions' on the Pipeline
2. Add the following in Buildspec 'Install' phase:

   - apt-get install jq
3. Add the following in Buildspec where you need to get the commit message:

   - COMMIT_MSG=$(aws codepipeline list-pipeline-executions  --pipeline-name  --max-items 1 | jq -r '.pipelineExecutionSummaries[0].sourceRevisions[0].revisionSummary')
   - echo $COMMIT_MSG

I hope this answer was helpful.

Ref:

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codepipeline/list-pipeline-executions.html

[3] https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: So for my example, how would I get back information like `pr/1234` similar to how `CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER` supplies in CodeBuild?

Comment: This does seem closer, but I'm still not seeing `pr/1234` where AWS CodeBuild would have this as the `CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_TRIGGER`?